# How do I place graphics within text of an enumerate?

Tags: graphics, enumerate, wrapfigure

I have a list full of text but also need a graphic to be within it, on the right hand side, and have text wrap around it.

I have been looking around and found really nothing useful and when I do, it just plops it on the bottom.

**Preamble:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper, portrait, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[svgnames,table,xcdraw,dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadings,patterns}
\pagenumbering{roman}
```

**Snipped...document**

```
\section*{Procedure}

\noindent \textbf{Directions:}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \itemsep 0em
        \item Place the following into a 250 ml round-bottomed flask:
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item 27.0 g of sodium bromide
            \item 20.0 ml of \textit{n}-butyl alcohol
            \item 30 ml of water
        \end{enumerate}
        \item Place into an ice-water bath
        \item Cool briefly
        \item Slowly add 23 ml of concentrated sulphuric acid while stirring using the magnetic stirring apparatus
        \item Fit the flask with a water-cooled condenser 
        \begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{exp14_fig1.pdf}
        \caption{Condenser}
        \end{wrapfigure}
        \item Heat the flask using the magnetic stirrer until the reaction mixture is boiling and note the time
        \item Adjust the stirring hot plate to maintain a brisk, steady reflux with \textit{vigorous} stirring 
        \item Note the separation due to density differences
        \item Reflux for fifty minutes
        \item Cool to room temperature
        \item Set up a steam distillation apparatus using a 100 ml round bottom flask as a receiver
```

[image: my version is here]

[eps file](http://www.weinraub.net/images/exp14_fig1.eps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is specific to [`wrapfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) being in a list.

One way around this problem is to adjust the margins within the list manually, and placing the figure in the appropriate position. Below I've used the power of LaTeX3's [`xgalley`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xgalley) to set some relative margins within the `enumerate`. The image is put flush right inside a zero-height `tabular` (using `\hfill\smash{..}`).

As a result of the construction, some fiddling is required to achieve a desirable result. For example, the `figure` counter is manually stepped in order to allow a typical `\caption`-like heading to be placed. Additionally a vertical strut is introduced to increase the gap between the image and the "caption".

Finally, the (relative) margin adjustment is placed inside a group to limit the scope of the change.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
% http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/media/conferences/tug-2015/0302-Joseph-Wright/
\usepackage{xgalley}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \SetAbsMargins \galley_margins_set_absolute:nn % {<left margin>}{<right margin>}
\cs_new_eq:NN \SetRelMargins \galley_margins_set_relative:nn % {<left margin>}{<right margin>}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section*{Procedure}

\noindent
\textbf{Directions:}
\begin{enumerate}
  \itemsep 0em
  \item Place the following into a 250 ml round-bottomed flask:
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item 27.0 g of sodium bromide
    \item 20.0 ml of \textit{n}-butyl alcohol
    \item 30 ml of water
  \end{enumerate}
  \item Place into an ice-water bath
  \item Cool briefly
  \item Slowly add 23 ml of concentrated sulphuric acid while stirring using the magnetic stirring apparatus
  \item Fit the flask with a water-cooled condenser
  \hfill\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{c@{}}
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\normalbaselineskip}{%
      \includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{example-image}} \\
    \refstepcounter{figure}%
    \rule{0pt}{\normalbaselineskip}% Vertical strut
    Figure~\thefigure:~Condenser
  \end{tabular}}

  \begingroup
  \SetRelMargins{0pt}{.3\textwidth}
  \item Heat the flask using the magnetic stirrer until the reaction mixture is boiling and note the time
  \item Adjust the stirring hot plate to maintain a brisk, steady reflux with \textit{vigorous} stirring 
  \item Note the separation due to density differences
  \item Reflux for fifty minutes
  \endgroup
  \item Cool to room temperature
  \item Set up a steam distillation apparatus using a 100 ml round bottom flask as a receiver
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The list items themselves are very short, and therefore brings into question the need for (relative) margin adjustments using something as powerful as `xgalley`. However, in a more general setting, the above would work as well.

That said, you could have achieved a similar result with some manual line-breaking and using `\item[]`s where there are no enumerations.

Comment: This one did the trick, I moved the endgroup further down since my actual image was much taller, but this made it work nice.  Thank you.  What made the text wrap *better* than the previously answered question above?

Comment: @JonathanWeinraub: Of course, you have to adjust the `\endgroup` depending on your image height. There are also other tricks to pull, but it depends heavily on your document construction. An [`xgalley`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xgalley) approach seemed feasible in this instance. I don't know how to answer your last question, since I don't understand your reference to "*better*".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, using the `resume*` feature of the `enumitem` package. It consists in closing the `enumerate` environment before the inclusion of the image, and create side to side two `minipage` environments, top-aligned. The left-hand side minipage contains the resumed enumerate, and the right-hand side the image and its caption. At the end of these environments, another resumed enumerate.    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{array, tabularx, enumitem, caption}

```
\begin{document}

\section*{Procedure}
\noindent \textbf{Directions:}
\begin{enumerate}[nosep]
  \itemsep 0em
  \item Place the following into a 250 ml round-bottomed flask:
        \begin{enumerate}[noitemsep]
          \item 27.0 g of sodium bromide
          \item 20.0 ml of \textit{n}-butyl alcohol
          \item 30 ml of water
        \end{enumerate}
  \item Place into an ice-water bath
  \item Cool briefly
  \item Slowly add 23 ml of concentrated sulphuric acid while stirring using the magnetic stirring apparatus
\end{enumerate}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
  \item Fit the flask with a water-cooled condenser
  \item Heat the flask using the magnetic stirrer until the reaction mixture is boiling and note the time
  \item Adjust the stirring hot plate to maintain a brisk, steady reflux with \textit{vigorous} stirring
  \item Note the separation due to density differences
  \item Reflux for fifty minutes
  \item Cool to room temperature
  \item Set up a steam distillation apparatus using a 100 ml round bottom flask as a receiver
  \item Add 50 ml of water and and distil adding water as needed to keep volume constant until no more water-insoluble droplets come over (can be tested by collecting a few drops of distillate in a\emph{dry} test tube to see if any oily droplets are still present)
  \item Pour the distillate into a separatory funnel
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering\captionsetup{labelfont=sc}\renewcommand\figurename{Fig.}
  \raisebox{-0.95\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{exp14_fig1}}
  \captionof{figure}{Condenser}\label{cond}
\end{minipage} \vspace*{-3pt}
\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
  \item Add 20 ml of water, stopper, and shake (the butyl bromide now forms the \emph{lower} layer since water and $ n $-butyl bromide have densities of $1.0$ g/ml and $ 1.3 $ g/ml, respectively)
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I added my version.  I do not get the *tightness* around the figure you did.  How can this be corrected, I updated my question to reflect what I did.

Comment: Could you post the image?

Comment: It's above in my original question...

Comment: I mean the graphics file, so that I can test.

Comment: oh... i added a link above, here it is as well:  http://www.weinraub.net/images/exp14_fig1.eps

Comment: I've updated my answer with your date. Is that OK now?