# Latex Image left and text right and down

Tags: graphics, text

im tring to do something like this image in tex:

[image]

I found examples where the text is in the right but doesnt go belowe when it passes the image. Is any way to acomplish that?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome. Yes, it is possible to achieve this, but what is best for you depends on the details of your document. So you may want to upload a minimal working example that lets others gauge what might be the best solution.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Hi, thanks for the reply, I don't have much yet, I am doing a report for a school project. And that example I think it fits good. Right now I have a center image and the text below, thinks its better to have the text on the right so the reader may check the image while reading.

Comment: Well, you seem to have an `enumerate` list, so this is more tricky. See e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/280549) for a way of wrapping it around the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you can use the `wrapfig` package.

For example:

```
% preamble
\documentclass[12pt, a4, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% body
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]  % some text
%%%%% your figure starts here %%%%%
\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{5cm}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{image.png}
\end{wrapfigure}
%%%%% your figure ends here %%%%%
\lipsum[1-6]  % some text
\end{document}
```

You can check all the options in the documentation [here](https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig/wrapfig-doc.pdf).

---

Another possible option would be using multiple columns, and that can be achieved using the package *multicols*.
[Here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multiple_columns) you can find several examples of what you want to achieve.

In your case, try using:

```
% preamble
\documentclass[12pt, a4, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicols}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

% body
\begin{document}
%%%%% Start multicols %%%%%
\begin{multicols}{2}
%%%%% your figure starts here %%%%%
\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.8\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image.png}
\caption{You can add captions}
\end{wrapfigure}
%%%%% your figure ends here %%%%%
\lipsum[1-6]  % some text
%%%%% End the multicolumn environment %%%%%
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer so that the code is completely compileable.

Comment: Thanks for the aswer, I tried do that but for some reason it doesn't work, here is my tex code: [link](https://imgur.com/QVBV00u) and here is the result [link](https://imgur.com/bmj5Q9B), as you can see the text don't go below the image, maybe it is because that it is a list. Also I need to put a blank caracter (where the mouse curser is) or the image go below, thats why the text is a bit below the image, is any way to fix this as well? Thank you.

Comment: I'm going to update the answer with another possible option.